# lossless PNG to video in Imagemagick

Tags: video, ffmpeg, png, imagemagick, lossless

As an intermediate step in creating an animation, I need to put a bunch of sequential PNGs into a movie file. I tried **ffmpeg** but was getting compression and artifacting even when I set quality to maximum.

Because this clip will be used in ANOTHER clip, I'd very much rather not compress it twice.

So I'm looking at Imagemagick to get a lossless PNG to Video conversion but am having trouble finding an equivalent command line call.

Any help?

Comment: You could supply the original command you used and we can tell you what's wrong with it.

Comment: did you use "-vcodec rawvideo" and not select a specific codec , nor shrunk the resolution in ffmpeg and still got compression?

Answer (score 3):

As you haven't given the command line you used we can only guess, but this ffmpeg command will generate a lossless video clip from files named `frame00.png`, `frame01.png`, `frame02.png`, etc.

```
ffmpeg -i frame%02d.png -codec png out.mov
```

The resulting video should work as input to at least `ffmpeg`, `mplayer` and VLC.

Adjust the framerate using an `-r` option *before* the `-i`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think Imagemagick has an appropriate tool, but this can be done with `mencoder`. You didn't specify how the encoded video should look, so I suggest lossless (`crf=0`) h.264, and will use that for this example.

```
mencoder -ovc x264 -x264encopts crf=0 -of rawvideo  mf://*.png -o video.h264
```

This will result in a raw h.264 stream with one frame for every *.png file in the current directory.

The stream can be muxed into a container or directly modified with some other software.